# JSON Get Data With Ajax Pagination

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

It's my JSON data. How can i paginate this data for day?

```json
{
  "15-02-2019": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "doctor_id": 1,
      "appointment_date": "2019-02-15 11:00:00",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "doctor_id": 1,
      "appointment_date": "2019-02-15 21:00:00",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  ],
  "16-02-2019": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "doctor_id": 1,
      "appointment_date": "2019-02-16 09:00:00",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Adding and subtracting these data possible. I tried with table populator but i can't do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "paginating"? Also, it seems that they are already grouped by day.

Comment: I want this style (https://jsfiddle.net/albertortizl/v7dgqyq2/4/).

Comment: Well, you only have a JSON file. Did you try something for the table part? You have the whole code there...

Comment: https://github.com/dexma/jquery-table-populator

Comment: i tried this demo but i can't get days.

Comment: What do you mean by days? Do you want to get only the day?

Comment: **"15-02-2019": [** = Day

Comment: i want to take appointment_date in this day

Answer (score 0):

My Friend, this is what you need :

[Fractal Laravel](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)

It will consume any data source, transform it and paginate it according to your specification.